# Como puedo devolver un xml con DOMDocument PHP

Tags: php, doctrine

tengo problemas al intentar devolver un XML que me genera DOMDocument y me lo guarda en mi proyecto de php, lo que quiero hacer es que se muestre ese fichero xml una vez lo genera con los valores pero me aparece el siguiente error:

> Error de lectura XML: no se encuentra el elemento raíz Ubicación:
> http://localhost/M7_Entrada/?data=15/04/2020 Número de línea 2,
> columna 1:

El fichero xml que me genera es el siguiente:

> ```
> <eventos>
>   <concierto>
>     <titol>THE VERY BEST OF DIRE STRAITS</titol>
>     <subtitol>bROTHES iN bAND. dIRE sTRAITS.</subtitol>
>     <data>15/04/2020</data>
>     <hora>21:30</hora>
>     <lugar>SALA BARTS</lugar>
>   </concierto>
> </eventos>
> ```

El parte del método para generar el XML:

```
            public function createXML($data){
            $root = $xmlDoc->appendChild($xmlDoc->createElement("eventos"));
            $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
      
             header("Content-Type: text/xml");
   
             $xmlDoc->formatOutput = true;
   
            $file_name = 'Espectacles.xml';
            
            $xmlDoc->save("./" . $file_name);
            
            return $file_name;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de     `$xmlDoc->save("./" . $file_name);`

usa `echo $xmlDoc->saveXML()`

eso escapa el xml al navegador en lugar de guardarlo

referencia: https://www.php.net/manual/es/domdocument.savexml.php

para que se reconozca como XML usa `header ("Content-Type:text/xml");`

PROCURA QUE NO TENGAS NADA ANTES DE COLOCAR EL HEADER.
para que funcione debes colocar el header antes de toda salida al navegador.

Comment: Me devuelve una respuesta con el xml pero en el navegador me sale con error,  si intento descargarlo me sale lo siguiente: 

<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/locale/intl.css" type="text/css"?><parsererror xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/newlayout/xml/parsererror.xml"/>

Comment: Adjunto una captura del resultado: https://i.imgur.com/p63hhel.png

Comment: ve la edición de la respuesta, si ves tu salida hay un salto de linea antes del xml debes eliminarlo

Comment: Siii, pero no sé donde se produce ese salto de linea dentro de mi código

Comment: Debes de buscarlo, tienes que debuguear tu código.